# Mongoengine: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__auto_convert'

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a table with following implementation

```
from mongoengine import StringField, Document, EmbeddedDocument, EmbeddedDocumentField

class ProjectMemberKey(EmbeddedDocument):
    member_email = StringField(required=False)
    project_id = StringField(required=False)


class ProjectMember(Document,Entity):
    key = EmbeddedDocumentField(ProjectMemberKey, primary_key=True)
    member_type = StringField()

    def __init__(self,key,member_type):
        super(ProjectMember, self).__init__()
        Entity.__init__(self)

        self.key = key
        self.member_type = member_type
```

And if I ran this query

```
projects = projects = ProjectMember.objects(member_type='manager')
print(projects)
```

the below error comes.

```
   print(projects)
  File "D:\project\project_name\venv\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\queryset.py", line 73, in __repr__
    self._populate_cache()
  File "D:\project\project_name\venv\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\queryset.py", line 129, in _populate_cache
    self._result_cache.append(next(self))
  File "D:\project\endee\venv\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\queryset\base.py", line 1577, in __next__
    doc = self._document._from_son(
  File "D:\project\project_name\venv\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", line 811, in _from_son
    obj = cls(__auto_convert=False, _created=created, **data)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__auto_convert'
```

And if I remove the **init** method from ProjectMember class it started to work well, which means I am missing something in init method.

Please help, any help is really appreciated.

To be exact I need **init** method to call Entity class init. If any further information is required please comment, I will add that info in question to make it better.

Thanks

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it seems original class may get many other arguments - and you should also get them in your class as `*args`, `**kwargs` - `def __init__(self,key,member_type, *args, **kwars):` and sent to original `__init__` - `super(ProjectMember, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @furas Thanks for your response. Adding ```*args, **kwars``` in ```__init___``` works and resolve the issue, although I have edited question with Traceback ass well